Как добиться идентичности вёрстки и в эмуляторе и в студии и на реальном устройстве?
Во всех трёх местах разное расположение элементов.
У реального устройства размер экрана 1280x720 размер 5".
Cоздал виртуальное устройство с такими же параметрами
и в дизайнере выбрал его же.
Везде всё по разному.
Пробовал выбрать готовое устройство с близкими или даже равными праметрами - тоже не совпадает.

смирись. реальное устройство всегда отличается от эмуляторов и симуляторов
